# How to fix TypeError can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I am practice list and I get TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

How to fix it ?

My code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
tag_list= ['Flying','Flight']

links = ['https://goo.gl/'+x for x in tag_list+'/text']
print links
```

it will give me error but if I edit my code to this , it will work.

```
tag_list= ['Flying','Flight']

links = ['https://goo.gl/'+x for x in tag_list]
print links
```

May I ask how to fix `links = ['https://goo.gl/'+x for x in tag_list+'/text']`

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: What do you want to get by doing `tag_list + 'text'`?  `['Flyingtext','Flighttext']` ?

Comment: you can concatenate two strings or two lists ie. `tag_list + ['text']`

Comment: i want output is ['goo.gl/Flying/text'] because i what res = requests.get(links)

Comment: You can do `['https://goo.gl/{}/text'.format(x) for x in tag_list]`

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you cannot add a string and a list using the operator `+`.